# Summing Stereo to mono?

Tags: stereo, to, mono

Can some help me please..

Im doing the sound editing for small animation, I want to use the sound effects which are in stereo, on to the mono track.. I dont want to use the splitted channels of the stereo track onto the mono track..

So can any body tell me how to sum the stereo to mono before I put them onto mono track?

Im using pro tools..

Comment: no way, just in 11

Answer (score 2):

If you assign the output of your stereo tracks to a mono bus, set the input of a mono track to the bus and then record to the mono track, you will get a stereo to mono downmix. However, you should be careful to monitor the mono track, as it's very possible that the combination of the L and R channels will cause phasing.

I'd recommend using a single channel from the stereo pair on the mono track instead.

Comment: Also, to get the equivalent level, you'll need to trim your stereo track by 6dB. 